# how to forge reveal operation by rpc

Tags: rpc, reveal

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@bakenrolls/sending-multiple-transactions-in-one-batch-using-tezos-rpc-6cab3a21f254) to construct operation. But when I try to construct a reveal operation, it always failed.
[image]

params:

```
{
    "contents": [
        {
            "kind": "reveal",
            "source": "tz1buwfQ3j7gTSM5QU8bmG2YnfH8zEnsjm92",
            "fee": "1000000",
            "counter": "540140",
            "gas_limit": "100000",
            "storage_limit": "100000",
            "phk": "edpkvJ4LqnbAVXoK12Q1HFuP42UTWcfJtixgKVimCEeStCZwi91x9B"
        }
    ],
    "branch": "BM42s1GKSg6zSyNunMWEiix6weFcynCCUS3QwJ246hvb81uSCCW"
}
```

response:

```
Failed to parse the request body: No case matched:
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of endorsement
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of seed_nonce_revelation
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of double_endorsement_evidence
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of double_baking_evidence
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of activate_account
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of proposals
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of ballot
  Missing object field public_key
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of transaction
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of origination
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of delegation
```

and my source and phk is correct.

Comment: It could be that their public RPC does not allow reveal operations. Try your operation against a local node.
What you have looks correct. I'd suggest using the `tezos-client` to do a reveal and use the `-l` flag which will show you all the debug input/output that it does. Might give you some insight as to what you are missing.

Answer (score 4):

Rename `pkh` to `public_key`, edpk.. is a public key and not a public key hash (pkh). You can find the expected json format in the [documentation](http://doc.tzalpha.net/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-forge-operations). You also have to decrease the value of `storage_limit` to 60 000 or less. Hard limits can be fetched from the [../context/constant](https://babylonnet.tezos.org.ua/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants) endpoint.